# Java get random double between two doubles

Tags: java, random

I want to get a random between two doubles.
Example:

```
0.00 and 0.50
```

then get random between them
output is:

```
0.23
```

how do i do this with java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, for this range [min,max]

```
return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
```